# Why is the result of this product operation wrong?

Tags: arduino-uno

I had a problem in a program where the result of product is not what it's supposed to be. For example: 775*775 gives 10801 instead of 6006025.

To try to isolate and resolve the problem, I made a simple sketch to test the result of different products. What I found is that if I do the same product in this way: 775/100.00*775/100.00 then multiply the result by 10000 I get the right value: 600625.00

The attached pictures illustrate what I said.

While I can use this solution in my initial program by I still want to do the multiplication directly as more operations means more time.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer overflow. You're multiplying an `int` by an `int` then assigning it to a `long`.  Instead if you multiply a `long` by a `long`, or an `int` by a `long`, or a `long` by an `int`, it should work.

```
unsigned long res = 775L * 775;
```

The `L` suffix tells the compiler to treat it as a long, not an int.